# How to inherent from Kinetic.Rect

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am drawing a raster using [Kineticjs](http://kineticjs.com/). This works using Kinetic.Rect. Now I want to use other objects than [Kinetic.Rect](http://kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Rect.php). In this object I should be able to save the x and y of the position in the raster. I have got to following code:

```
function Tile(rasterX, rasterY, occupied, config) {
    Kinetic.Rect.call(this, config);
    this.rasterX = rasterX;
    this.rasterY = rasterY;
    this.occupied = occupied;
}

Tile.prototype = new Kinetic.Rect();

Tile.prototype.constructor = Tile;
```

Now I changes the code of the Kinetic.Rect creating from (this works):

```
var tile = new Kinetic.Rect({
                                width: drawWidth,
                                height: drawHeight,
                                stroke: 'black',
                                fill: 'grey',
                                x: x,
                                y: j * drawHeight
                            });
```

to:

```
var tile = new Tile(j, i, false, {
                            width: drawWidth,
                            height: drawHeight,
                            stroke: 'black',
                            fill: 'grey',
                            x: x,
                            y: j * drawHeight
                        });
```

Somehow the config is not passed to the Kinetic.Rect constructor properly because the x and y of all the tiles created are the same (Right bottom corner of the canvas). The colors however are there.

Comment: Hum, could it be that the `Kinetic.Rect` constructor logic mutate some part of the object that would lead to this wierd behavior? Try using `Tile.prototype = Object.create(Kinetic.Rect.prototype);` for inherithing instead.

Comment: Thanks! That did work. Can you post it as an answer? And explain the difference between Object.create and my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum, could it be that the `Kinetic.Rect` constructor logic mutate some part of the object that would lead to this wierd behavior?

Try using `Tile.prototype = Object.create(Kinetic.Rect.prototype);` for inherithing instead.

The difference is that `Object.create` will return a new object with the specified prototype while the `new` operator when doing `Tile.prototype = new Kinetic.Rect();` also sets up the prototype chain, but also runs the constructor logic wich might have undesireble side-effects.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I extend Kinetic objects

```
MyCircle = function(config) {
        Kinetic.Circle.call(this, $.extend({
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        }, config));
};
MyCircle.prototype = {
        myFunc: function() {
        }
}
Kinetic.Global.extend(MyCircle, Kinetic.Circle);
```

Comment: Do you know the difference?